# Weierstrass points of $C$ and totally ramified covers $C\to\mathbb P^1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $C$ be any compact Riemann surface of genus $g$. I'd like to show that $C$ has a Weierstrass point, in two steps: by first showing that to give a Weierstrass point $P$ of $C$ is the same as to give a degree $g$ cover $C\to\mathbb P^1$, totally ramified at $P$. Second step: showing that there exists $P$ such that $h^0(C,gP)\geq 2$.

A Weierstrass point is a point $P\in C$ such that $h^0(C,K(-gP))>0$.

It is clear to me that, given a Weierstrass point $P\in C$, we can construct a degree $g$ cover $C\to\mathbb P^1$. Indeed, one considers the linear series $|gP|$. The degree $g$ cover $$\phi:C\overset{|gP|}{\longrightarrow}\mathbb P^1$$ makes sense because, by Riemann-Roch, $h^0(C,gP)\geq 2$. But how to see that $\phi$ is totally ramified at $P$?

Conversely, suppose we have $\phi:C\to\mathbb P^1$ of degree $g$ and totally ramified at $P$. Again Riemann-Roch says that $P$ is Weierstrass if and only if $h^0(C,gP)\geq 2$. So, how to see that there are at least two independent rational functions $f_0,f_1$ on $C$ such that $\textrm{ord}_Pf_i\geq -g$?

Finally, to conclude that $C$ has a Weierstrass point, we have to show that there exists $P\in C$ such that $h^0(C,gP)\geq 2$. Any clue on how to do that?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand the relation between step 1 and step 2. Riemann-Roch implies that $h^0(C, K(-gp))>0$ if and only if $h^0(C, gp)\ge 2$. Why do you add step 1 ? Note that a Weierstrass point $P$ gives a morphism $C\to\mathbb P^1$ totally ramified at $P$, but of degree $\le g$.

Comment: Maybe I was unclear, sorry. You are saying: why not to show directly that there exists $P$ with $h^0(K(-gP))>0$? I want to use that $P$ is Weierstrass iff $h^0(gP)\geq 2$ (and I'm not able to prove this equivalence properly: this is the first part of my question), and then show that there exists such a $P$.

Comment: Also, correct me if I am wrong, but I think that $P$ Weierstrass induces a $g:1$ map to $\mathbb P^1$ because there are two independent sections in $H^0(gP)$: we may choose $s_0$ such that $Z(s_0)=gP$ and $s_1$ such that $s_1(P)\neq 0$. So $s_1/s_0\in K(C)$ should give $C\to\mathbb P^1$ of degree $g$. Am I mistaken?